# C# pack.xz garbage after end of pack archive

Tags: java, c#, unpack, minecraft-forge, xz

I have a C# program that should download a file from the internet and extract it.

The file is a .pack.xz file, i have no problem extracting the .xz, i tried even manually checking the checksum of the file and it was downloaded correctly.
For instance, one of the files i have to download is this:

http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.11/2.3.3/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.3.jar.pack.xz

I downloaded it from the browser, then extracted the .xz part with 7zip and it was ok. Now i have a .pack file, i tried to unpack it with Java's unpack200 but it says me "garbage after end of pack archive".

It extracts the file anyway but it's corrupted infact if i open it with winrar it says unexpected end of archive. The jar file i extracted was 2,350,874 bytes while it should have been 2,553,197 bytes.

I really don't know how to solve it. I even checked some online programs but they seems to do the same thing i do the same way i do it so i can't figure out what's the problem

Comment: As a workaround, why don't you grab this file from a different Maven repository? The Central Repository has this JAR as well as a bunch of newer versions. See [page 1](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|a|g%3A"com.typesafe.akka"ANDa%3A"akka-actor_2.11") and [page 2](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|2|g%3A"com.typesafe.akka"%20AND%20a%3A"akka-actor_2.11") which has version 2.3.3 as in your original URL.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I used that pattern for all of my files! Now i can even put away the libraries for xz and reduce the size of my exe!! Thanks again

Comment: No problem; I'll add this as an answer since comments are ephemeral.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can grab this JAR from a different Maven repository, such as the Central Repository (which has this specific JAR and a bunch of newer versions). See [this search](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|a|g%3A"com.typesafe.akka"ANDa%3A"akka-actor_2.11") to find all the versions. The older version in your original link is on the second page of this search (although it may be less functional or less secure than the latest version).